# sealed method in android

Tags: java, android, sealed

I Am a newbie and I am reding about sealed keyword and referred [sealed object](http://java.labsoft.dcc.ufmg.br/apiminer/static/docs/reference/javax/crypto/SealedObject.html). I googled but could not find a simple example of using sealed method in android.I tried something like

```
class A
{
//declarations

}

class B extends A
{

//here i would like to use my sealed override keyword

}
```

Can anyone tell me how to use this sealed method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a java class, not Android specific.  Google for examples.

Comment: i would like to implement the sealed concept in android.

Answer (score 1):

'final' is the keyword in Java to achieve sealed behavior. I assume you are coming from C# background. If it is so, please note that in java all the methods are virtual by default and adding final keyword right before method name will prevent it from being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice sample example for [Securing Java Objects for Plain Text Transport](http://blog.arc90.com/2008/08/26/securing-java-objects-for-plain-text-transport/) also reading the [IBM docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.security.component.60.doc/security-component/JceDocs/api_sealedobjectclass.html) also gives you a better idea.

Comment: like Override in android if i use @sealedOverride it is throwing an error. Is my implementation correct here?

Answer (score 0):

Sealed class is used to define the inheritance level of a class. A class, which restricts inheritance for security reason is declared, sealed class.Sealed class is the last class in the hierarchy. Sealed class can be a derived class but can't be a base class.A sealed class cannot also be an abstract class. Because abstract class.

```
class A
{

public class B
{

 public void display()
     {
      }

    }


public class c extends B
 {

 public override sealed void Display()
            {

            }
 }
}
```